# Remove Middle Name from "Last, First Middle"

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of people whose names are in excel in the following format in a single cell: "Last, First Middle". I'm looking to only keep the first and last name in this format: "First Last". What would be the best way to accomplish this? I've tried text replace, a few random formulas I've googled but nothing works and am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super knowledgeable, but I believe you can select the second row (meaning the one with FIRST MIDDLE and use find/replace to delete anything after a space. Sorry I don't know that much but this link may help you: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/527559-deleting-everything-after-first-space-cell.html

Also, searching "excel, remove after space" in Google may help too.

Hope everything works out well.

EDIT: Here's another link : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1623-excel-extract-text-before-space.html

Comment: Hi mmv456, thanks for the info. I'll go ahead and research those links!

Comment: mmv - Great resources you mentioned. Both are largely applicable to Tim's situation.

Answer (score 0):

One more shorter formula for you to try,

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1),LEN(A1))&" "&LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1))`

Hope this helps
[image]